# How to use language independent canonical form in list entities in LUIS?

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding, nlu

When using a closed list entity in LUIS, there always is a canonical form and optional multiple synonyms.

In the example below there is the canonical form "green" and one possible synonym "olive".

When the user says "olive", the frontend software doesn't have to care about "olive", it get's the resolution "green" from LUIS instead.

But since language may change and the frontend software should be language independent, what I actually want to be delivered from the API is not the english term "green", but a language independent identifier string for green, like "my_chatbot_green_id".

Is it recommendable, to use the identifier as canocical form, and add "green" as a synonym instead? I suppose it isn't. Is there then any other way to achieve language independent identifiers?

**Original Example**

```
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "ColorListEntity",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "green",
          "list": [
            "olive"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "blue",
          "list": [
            "azure"
          ]
        }
      ],
```

**Does this make sense?**

```
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "ColorListEntity",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "my_chatbot_green_id",
          "list": [
            "olive",
            "green"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "my_chatbot_blue_id",
          "list": [
            "blue",
            "azure"
          ]
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a common identifier for each color and add multilingual synonyms as you want to the list.

Comment: So, that would be the same as suggested under "Does this make sense?" ? Using the identifier as canonical form? And hoping, it doesn't confuse the nlu?

Comment: yes, it won't affect the nlu. All the colors you add to the list are extracted as the cannonical form.